# Success Percentage not handled correctly by Surefire

Tags: maven, testng, surefire

I have a wait test that I expect to fail on occasion because the test threads get too out of sync. So I'm setting the `successPercentage` and `invocationCount` to handle the occasional acceptable failure. If the code's broken, none of the invocations will pass.

When I run the test in IntelliJ, everything's fine. But when I try and do a build in maven, I get the following

```
Tests run: 1407, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There are test failures.
```

Looking in restng-results.xml, I see this:

```
<test-method status="SUCCESS_PERCENTAGE_FAILURE" signature="waits()" name="waits" duration-ms="1000" started-at="2012-03-02T13:51:58Z" finished-at="2012-03-02T13:51:59Z">
```

And in TEST-TestSuite.xml, I see:

```
<testcase classname="com.casenet.integration.filesystem.TriggerFileListenerTest" time="1" name="waits">
  <error type="java.lang.AssertionError" message="expected:&lt;EXECUTE&gt; but was:&lt;TIMED_OUT&gt;">java.lang.AssertionError: expected:&lt;EXECUTE&gt; but was:&lt;TIMED_OUT&gt;
```

The rest of the testng generated files seem to think everything passed. But it looks like that surefire is getting confused by `SUCCESS_PERCENTAGE_FAILURE` or the `<error/>` element into thinking something's gone wrong when in fact nothing unexpected happened.

Anyone know if this is a known problem or if there's a solution available?

Comment: 1) You didn't mention the version of maven or surefire. 2) you'll get better service on the maven users list for something like this.

Comment: @bmargulies 1) maven 2.2.1, surefire 2.12, testng 6.1.1 2) thanks, maybe I'll give them a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is an [open surefire bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-654) on this, which also seems to have a patch and workaround.

Comment: Using a patched version of maven isn't an option, so your answer translates to "maven doesn't support this feature at this time". So I either have to disable the test or hack something.

Comment: answer by @blagae is more complete

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: The fix for this issue has made it into release version 6.8.17. I have edited my answer accordingly.

---

I know I'm digging up an old issue here, but it looks like we have a fix for this situation, and I can imagine that people want to know about this. In order to use the fix, you need SureFire 2.18 and at least TestNG 6.8.17.

You can refer to the following bug reports for the full information backstory:

https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-654 for the initial issue, as linked to in the answer from @Raghuram. Short version: SureFire reported false negatives.

https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-1113 for a bug I reported on the fix for SUREFIRE-654. It turned out to be not a SureFire problem, but a TestNG bug which had been introduced in version 5.14 (in 2010 !). Short version: SureFire (I thought) reported false positives.

https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/566 for the actual TestNG bug, which was fixed by Vladislav Rassokhin and merged into a release recently. Short version: TestNG actually created false positives, which were then parsed by SureFire as successful tests.